# ActionView::Template::Error (kids.css isn't precompiled):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm getting this vierd error. I have added kids.css.less to my application.css.
I can avoid this error if i add to `config.assets.precompile` in `application(and/or environment file)` array, but this is not solution that i would like to use

here is my app.css.less:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require kids.css.less
 */


 @import "theme_venera.less";

.white-card {
  .kid-word {
    h5 { font-size: @fontSizeSmall;}
  }
}
```

Which result me in kids.css isnt precompiled.

What am i missing?

UPD: This error happens when i only deploy on my production server. In my dev env i have "live" assets. I'm using capistrano to deploy, and my script containts assets:precompile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In development you should be assets debugging (disable the pipeline), to avoid sprockets to concatenate and minify your assets:

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

If you don't, Rails expects your assets to be compiled:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

And if you don't precompile them, it will try to compile them on request if you enable it:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Otherwise, if you don't disable the pipeline, don't compile them yourself, and don't allow Rails to do it, it will give you the error you're getting. In production, the usual practice is to precompile them. Live compilation can add a significant overhead, so you shouldn't rely on it. However, it's ok if you leave it enabled after precompiling: Rails will use your compilation first, and if it doesn't find the asset it's looking for there will compile it as an "emergency procedure" to avoid throwing an error.

You have all the information here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: i've read that guide, but didnt find anything that could help me. Updated my question

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain more. Again, the production section of my link contains everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake assets:precompile` in production mode to compile and compress your stylesheets and then run the application.

Comment: That's a bad advice assuming he's in development mode.

Comment: By default, the debug mode is on for the assets in development, so I presume he is in production mode.